# how to debug during API with laravel

Tags: laravel, api, debugging, terminal, postman

I run my laravel app @localhost.

````
```php artisan serve --host=localhostIP```
````

On top I run an Andoid app with the same base URL.

Could anyone tell me how can I debug incoming API´s calls
like if BASEURL/users is called?

Furthermore, how can I log the happening events in the console

Comment: for debbuging apis you have to use insomania

Answer (score 3):

I am developing API's with laravel too, i do it this way:

- `composer require laravel/homestead` to have it all in a vm  see https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead for more information, i use the "per project" installation
- Download `postman` to have the best tool for sending querys to your api and to test your api quick -> https://www.getpostman.com (i use it free)
- configure and run your homestead (it's not that complicated).
- your homestead is fit with php and xdebug enabled
- i am using phpStorm and have my vagrant setup as deployment target
- "listen to debug" with phpstorm
- to your GET requests, add a queryparam `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM`
- i can debug my api now
- i also wrote https://logcrawler.de to receive the log informations of all my api's and all my server

I hope, i could help you a little bit

Comment: The [Insomnia REST client](https://insomnia.rest/) is a nice alternative to Postman, both do the same job at the end of the day though. [:

Comment: What about post request?

Comment: @ortagon This will work no matter what method you will use, so it works with GET the same as with POST or HEAD or PATCH ... as long, as your app reacts on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is my way, but I think it's not good!

1. Create router api in config/web, Eg:

- router/api: `Route::post('/check_api', [CheckController::class, 'testFunc'])->name('api.check_api');`
- web/api: `Route::post('test/check_api', [CheckController::class, 'testFunc'])->name('test.check_api');`

2. Create a post by form or ajax in one resource/view like index
3. Go to page, and debug with phpstorm

Answer (score 0):

You can use logging feature of Laravel. Apply Logs on entry point of application to test whether API url is hitting or not.

Answer (score 0):

use postman
https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/ 
it's an excellent thing very much usefull